# Failed to get information on remote file - gitlab runner in openshift

Tags: ansible, openshift, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab-runner running in openshift. I am running a playbook using this image `registry.redhat.io/ansible-tower-38/ansible-runner-rhel7`

The gitlab ci file:

```
image:
  name: registry.redhat.io/ansible-tower-38/ansible-runner-rhel7

variables:
   FF_GITLAB_REGISTRY_HELPER_IMAGE: "true"

stages:
  - deploy
    
run-playbook:
  tags:
    - test

  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
  script:
    - sh add_user_to_etc.sh
    - export ANSIBLE_CONFIG="/builds/group-name/repo-name/ansible.cfg"
    - echo "$ANSIBLE_CONFIG"
    - ansible-playbook playbooks/linux-node.yml -e "ansible_user=$ROBOT_USERNAME ansible_ssh_pass=$ROBOT_PASSWORD"
```

The play file:

```
---
- name: Add Linux servers 
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  any_errors_fatal: true
  environment:
    http_proxy: "{{ proxy_global }}"
    https_proxy: "{{ proxy_global }}"
    no_proxy: "127.0.0.1"
  roles:
    - linux-node
```

The task where the error occurs:

```
- name: Build a JSON dashboard def
  template:
    src: templates/dashboard_summary.j2
    dest: /tmp/{{ BLAH }}_dashboard_summary.json
  force: yes
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

The error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/tmp/my-service-dev_dashboard_summary.json): sudo: PERM_SUDOERS: setresuid(-1, 1, -1): Operation not permitted\nsudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting\nsudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [1001010000, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted\nsudo: unable to initialize policy plugin\n"}
```

I'm guessing its because of the user `1001010000` openshift assigns. But other tasks are run using the robot user which has sudo permissions, those are all working fine. I don't know why this task alone uses `1001010000`. Or maybe i got it all wrong.

Comment: This task is delegated to localhost (e.g. the ansible runner itself, not the image it started for your pipeline from your ci file).

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thanks @Zeitounator